# Passing function to Knex select method breaks querying

Tags: node.js, knex.js

The code:

```
const knex = require("../../db/knex");

module.exports = (request, response) => {
  knex
    .select((builder) => {
      const select = request.query.select;

      if (select) {
        if (select.constructor === String) {
          builder.select(select);
        } else if (select.constructor === Array) {
          builder.select(...select);
        }
      } else {
        /* Anything that goes here or inside this function, breaks it. */
      }
    })
    .from("tags")
    .where((builder) => {
      const filter = request.query.filter;

      if (filter) {
        if (filter.constructor === Object) {
          builder.where(filter);
        } else if (filter.constructor === Array) {
          builder.where(...filter);
        }
      } else {
        builder.clear("where");
      }
    })
    .then((result) => response.json(result))
    .catch((error) => response.json({ ...error, message: error.stack }));
};
```

The full error:

```
{
    "length": 180,
    "name": "error",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42601",
    "position": "16",
    "file": "d:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_target.c",
    "line": "1296",
    "routine": "ExpandAllTables",
    "message": "error: select (select *) from \"tags\" - SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid\n    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Repositories\\projeto-integrador-dh-g1\\node_modules\\pg-protocol\\dist\\parser.js:278:15)\n    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Repositories\\projeto-integrador-dh-g1\\node_modules\\pg-protocol\\dist\\parser.js:126:29)\n    at Parser.parse (C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Repositories\\projeto-integrador-dh-g1\\node_modules\\pg-protocol\\dist\\parser.js:39:38)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\Repositories\\projeto-integrador-dh-g1\\node_modules\\pg-protocol\\dist\\index.js:10:42)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)\n    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)"
}
```

I'm using Express to manage the Node server and Knex to manage the database. In this route, if I remove the function from select, everything works. Tried everything, I can't understand why isn't working. Can anyone help me understand why is it breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, what is being done is considered by Knex a sub query. I've found out that the proper way to handle these conditions are by using [modify](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify).

I got to something like this now:

```
const knex = require("../../db/knex");

module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
  knex
    .from("tags")
    .modify((builder) => {
      const filter = request.query.filter;
      const select = request.query.select;
      const order = request.query.order;
      const id = request.params.id;

      if (select) {
        if (select.constructor === String || select.constructor === Object) {
          builder.select(select);
        } else if (select.constructor === Array) {
          builder.select(...select);
        }
      }

      if (id) {
        builder.where({ id: id }).first();
      } else if (filter) {
        if (filter.constructor === Object) {
          builder.where(filter);
        } else if (filter.constructor === Array) {
          builder.where(...filter);
        }
      }

      if (!id) {
        if (order) {
          if (order.constructor === String) {
            builder.orderBy(order);
          } else if (order.constructor === Array) {
            builder.orderBy(...order);
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .then((result) => response.json(result))
    .catch((error) => next(error));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select()` method in Knex takes in column names to select from your table. I don't think you can properly pass in a function like you're trying to do. You can do that in the `.where()` like you have. But I'd start by removing all of the `if/else` logic from inside of `select()`.

If you need to transform the data you're receiving, do that prior to building a query. Perhaps there might be other query building methods that would help you get the result that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found the solution and the problem. The problem is that Knex reads what I'm doing as a sub query. I had to use the [modify](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify)method to actually achieve the proper result.